# query with special charaters in sqoop

Tags: sqoop

Can we use query in sqoop options file like i used query with special characters when i ran the query its giving an error  **incorrect syntax near "\"** . Should I use any escape character in the properties file ?

In option file I have mentioned query and using in sqoop import command.
**Propertiesfile:**

```
--query "select top 10 source_system,company_code,gl_document,***************negative_posting_flag, to_number(to_varchar(to_date(create_tmstmp),'yyyymm')) as part_date from c_fin_a.gl_transaction_data where to_number(to_varchar(to_date(create_tmstmp),'yyyymm'))=201602 and \$CONDITIONS"
```

sqoop import command

```
  sudo sqoop import \
    --options-file /home/emaarae/sqoop_shell/sqoop_hdfs.properties \
    --append \
    --null-string '' \
    --null-non-string '' \
    --fields-terminated-by '\001' \
    --lines-terminated-by '\n' \
    --m 15
```

Comment: It says incorrect syntax there.

Have you tried testing the literal query in the main sqoop import command instead of including in --options-file yet? Does it executes properly?

Comment: Yes I tested in with main sqoop import command it executes without any warning.. I think its problem with the escape characters("") which has given in the options file.